# Creating an IAM inline policy throws API error (An error occurred describing your selected AMI You are not authorized to perform this operation)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Creating an IAM inline policy to allow the IAM user to attach a max of 20GB EBS volume, and only allow t2.micro Ubuntu instance from us-east-2 region. I have copied the ami for the same but in the conosle for IAM user it shows API error when trying to run the EC2 instance, what might be the problem.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AdminPermissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ssm:SendCommand",
            "ssm:GetCommandInvocation",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:StartInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:CreateTags"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "RunInstanceResourcePermissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:RunInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:::network-interface/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:::security-group/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:::subnet/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-0885b1f6bd170450c"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "LimitInstanceVolumeSize",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:RunInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:::volume/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "NumericLessThanEquals": {
                "ec2:VolumeSize": "20"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "LimitInstanceTypes",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:RunInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:::instance/ami-0885b1f6bd170450c"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:InstanceType":
                    "t2.nano"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: While trying to run the EC2 instance from IAM user AWS gives the error "An error occurred describing your selected AMI You are not authorized to perform this operation." I think using these policy the IAM user should atleast be able to launch every instance.